# How can I play my game in unity without the game being frozen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am following a tutorial to develop a game in Unity, (I am using Unity version 2021.3.4f1), but I have run into some sort of error where I am not able to play the game, it worked before but recently I could no longer play the game, I have to keep on pressing the step button, "Ctrl + Alt + P" (in the hotkey section) to play the game. I have tried creating a new project and creating the same game but the error still occurs. I have tried searching to fix the error but did not get any reasonable results to fix it.

Click the link to review the error in the picture.

[The game is playing but the character isn't falling down, the character should be falling down but it isn't, but when I keep pressing the step button (which is next to the pause button at the top), the character falls a little and then stops until I press the step button again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juhtp.png)

It would be really helpful if the error is fixed.

Comment: It sounds like you have a breakpoint in your code, since you can "step" over it to continue! Other than that, it's impossible to know what's going on in your project if you don't post any code and only a screenshot of a sprite :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that Error Pause is unchecked or just try to unclick Pause button at the top of Unity Editor
[image]